# ReactJS: How to detect if form has been inputted

Tags: reactjs, antd

I currently have a form and I'm struggling to detect if the user has inputted.

The scenario is that after inputting the form, the user cancels and a modal will appear that asks if they want to proceed without changing.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
```

My code for triggering the modal

```
if (!name){

    showModal()

}
```

Right now I'm having trouble detecting if form has been filled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "onChange" event to detect input element changes in the form.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Example From: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html